# Orthogonality of the Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, lorentz-symmetry

I want to derive the Lorentz equations without the postulate that the speed of light is constant in all reference frames. Let $L$ denote the matrix that transforms spacetime coordinates
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ t'\end{bmatrix} = L(v) \begin{bmatrix}x \\ t\end{bmatrix}
$$
depending on the velocity $v$. So far I have found that $L$ is of the form
$$
L(v) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\gamma      & - \gamma v \\
\varepsilon & \gamma
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $\gamma$ and $\varepsilon$ themselves depend on $v$. Since $L$ is an element of the special orthogonal group, $L^{-1} = L^\mathsf{T}$ implies $\varepsilon = \gamma v$ and $\det L = 1$ implies $\gamma = (1 + v^2)^{-1/2}$, completing the proof. But how can I argue that $L$ must be orthogonal in the first place? Why must it preserve the spacetime norm? How is this fact related to the conservation of energy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake in your proof: $L^{-1}\neq L^T$. The correct version is 
$$L^T \eta L =\eta,  \tag1$$
where $\eta$ is the Minkowski metric. That's why you have the wrong $\gamma$. The reason for this is because the Lorentz transformation is not part of the orthogonal group, it's part of the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group). The upshot is that we need the Lorentz transformations to preserve the quadratic form
$$\sum_{\mu,\nu=0}^3 x^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu}y^\nu \tag2$$
for every possible pair of 4-vectors $x^\mu$ and $y^\nu$. From (2) requirement you can derive the requirement in (1).

As for why it must preserve the form in (2), it's a sufficient (and possibly necessary) condition that any linear transformation has to obey if
\begin{align}
0 &= \sum_{\mu,\nu=0}^3 \eta_{\mu\nu} \Delta x^\mu \Delta x^\nu \\
  & = \sum_{\mu,\nu,\alpha\beta=0}^3 \eta_{\mu\nu} L^\mu_{\hphantom{\mu}\alpha'}\Delta x^{\alpha'} L^\mu_{\hphantom{\nu}\beta'}\Delta x^{\beta'}
\end{align}
for every $\Delta x^\nu$ that a light ray moves along (fancy way of saying "all observers see light moving with speed $c$").

Comment: Thanks alot! I vaguely recalled Lorentz transformations to be rotations but missed that they are not Euclidean.